# Custom loss function using multiple indirect values in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am using a Keras neural network inside a system of ODEs. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

And here is a function that describes my differential equations. That Keras model is used in the calculation of ODEs.

```
def dxdt_new(t, x, *args):
    N, beta, gamma, delta = args
    deltaInfected = beta * x[0] * x[1] / N
    quarantine = model.predict(np.expand_dims(x[:3], axis=0)) / N
    recoveredQ = delta * x[3]
    recoveredNoQ = gamma * x[1]
    S = -deltaInfected
    I = deltaInfected - recoveredNoQ - quarantine
    R = recoveredNoQ + recoveredQ
    Q = quarantine - recoveredQ
    return [S, I, R, Q]
```

And I need to use a custom loss function for training. Inside my loss function, I cannot use the values predicted by a neural network since I do not have real data on it. I am trying to use the values that are affected by the predicted value. So I do not use `y_true` and `y_pred`.

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    infected = K.constant(INFECTED)
    recovered = K.constant(RECOVERED)
    dead = K.constant(DEAD)
    pred = K.constant(predicted)
    loss = K.sum((K.log(infected) - K.log(pred[1][:] + pred[3][:]))**2)
    loss += K.sum((K.log(recovered + dead) - K.log(pred[2][:]))**2)
    return loss
```

But when I try to train my neural network, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

So it seems like this loss function does not work properly. How can I organize my code to get it to work? Is there any other way to construct a loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot use the values predicted by a neural network since I do not have real data on it

For the customized loss function to work with the [Backpropagation algorithm](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html), you need to have it defined in terms of `y_true` and `y_pred`. In the case when you do not have this data, or when your loss function is non differentiable, you have to use another algorithm to optimize the weights in your neural network. Some examples for this could be a [Genetic Algorithm](https://research.ijcaonline.org/volume77/number14/pxc3891153.pdf) or [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization).